# How to run a query several times?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a simple query that I want to run an unknown number of times (depending on given value from the table)

```
select * 
   from lotTable
   where lot = '1111'
```

I want to run that query X time depending on the cell called 'code' in the same lot line.
I try to use unsuccessfully for loops in PL/SQL.

This is the code I tried to run:

```
DECLARE Counter INT
DECLARE MaxC INT
    SET Counter = 0
    SET MaxC = (select code from lotTable where lot='1111')
    while MaxC => Counter
      BEGIN
        SET Counter += 1
        select * 
         from lotTable
         where lot = '1111'
      END
```

and this is the error
[image: error]

Comment: Well what does "unsuccessfully for loops in pl/sql" mean?  Please show code and problems.

Comment: To loop the way you intend, you need a cursor.

Comment: You need to [familiarise yourself with the PL/SQL language fundamentals](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e17126/fundamentals.htm#CIHEAFBJ); not sure if what you have is valid in any other DB, but it isn't anything like what you need for Oracle. Not really sure why you'd want exactly the same output repeated a number of times though, or where/how you want the data to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want the specific row from the table repeated `code` times, you coudl use a [hierarchical query](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17118/queries003.htm):

```
select * 
from (
  select *
  from lotTable
  where lot = 1111
)
connect by level <= code;
```

The inner query identifies the single row you're interested in, and the outer query uses the `connect by level` construct to repeat the row.

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee74a/1).

Without the inner query `connect by` gets a bit confused (see [this example with incorrect results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee74a/2)); there are workarounds and you could also use recursive subquery factoring to avoid that, but this is simpler.